# Firestore load document if user is a member

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have two collections: groups and users

I would like to perform a query that will return all groups where a user has a particular role assigned.

A group looks like this

```
{
  "name": "myGroupName",
  "members" : {
    "firstUsersID" :
      {
        "roles" : ["user", "admin"]
      },
      "secondUsersID" :
      {
        "roles" : ["user" ]
      },
  }
}
```

Is there a way to perform queries in react native/web SDK which will return

1. All groups where a given user e.g firstUserID is listed in the members map/object
2. All groups where a given user e.g firstUserId has a particular role e.g "admin"

Alternatively would I have to create an array/map on the user object listing their roles? Are there advantages/disadvantages to each route?

Currently I have the following which returns all groups

```
const colRef = collection(db, "groups");
const q = query(colRef)
const colSnap = await getDocs(q)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out I think

The following works

```
const colRef = collection(db, "groups");
const q = query(colRef, where("users." + user.uid + ".roles", "array-contains", "admin"))
```

In this case I am dynamically getting the uid of the current authenticated user but you could also hardcode it using

```
const q = query(colRef, where("users.firstUserID.roles", "array-contains", "admin"))
```